# Tips for an easy and great SVN integrated issue tracking system?

Tags: svn, documentation, issue-tracking, integrated

Hey I'm looking for some tips for a good and easy to install easy to use SVN integrated issue tracking system.

We are maybe 3 friends looking for something much simpler to install, like double click and install then maybe write some configuration files.

A local system would be good if there's a good installation guide to follow.
A web hosting system is preferred because then we don't have to get our own server.

I tried to install "Redmine", but the installation guide i was using was very long so i messed up somewhere.

I work as a C# developer, at work we use "Trac" but i read that its a huge work to install and configure tons of different modules so no thanks. And doesn't support multiple projects.

I tried SourceForge but encountered some SVN permission problems there, also I only get 1.4kBps when committing so that is too slow. Also their homepage loads too slow to, its going to be a pain to work there.

Anyone know any other system I can try? Preferable that has a short and simple installation guide. Thanks for any suggestions.

**choose GIT-hub. its smooth easy. uses git and we are just using it for some fun game projects with my friends, so the fact that all code is opensource doesn't matter.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use

- [github](https://github.com/)  (GIT, only public repositories for free)
- [bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/)  (GIT and Mercurial, private repositories for free)

If switching to [Mercurial](http://mercurial.selenic.com/) or [GIT](http://git-scm.com/) is an option. (And that switch would save you a lot of subversion-pain ;)

Comment: testing git hub at the moment

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to use a pre-packaged install of something like Redmine, such as the ones from [Bitnami](http://bitnami.org/stack/redmine).

Alternatively, get a integrated system such as [UberSvn](http://www.ubersvn.com/) or [Gforge](http://gforge.org/gf/) or go with a paid-for hosting solution such as Assembla's products.

I found installing Redmine to be a little tricky, but once I had it solved with Google's help it was easy and mainly things that experienced Ruby/Rails guys would already know. Once you have Ruby and dependencies installed it's easy to administer. Trac is easy too.

Answer (score 1):

Try installing trac. It shouldn't be too difficult. If it does give you problems, look at an online provider such as unfuddle.com or similar.

If you want multi-user, closed source hosting + project management online, be ready to pay $5-10/month. Single user or non-commercial projects are usually free.

Answer (score 0):

1. Assembla with SVN+Tickets (no install)
2. Mantis (PHP) as issue tracker on any hosting + own SVN